# Preventing the printing of bibliography items referenced after the bibliography is printed

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am working on a project application that encompasses several "independent" parts:

- Project description
- CV
- Budget
- Misc.

The project description references some bibliographic items, and a bibliography is printed at the end, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

% ... some preamble options ...

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

% ... project description with several \cite{}...

% We print the bibliography after the project description:
\printbibliography[heading=none]

% ... here come CV, budget, etc with biblatex calls

\end{document}
```

The issue here is that I am extracting bibliographic info for the CV, e.g. using `\citename{random_dude_2015}{author}`, which are not referenced in the project description. However, biblatex is printing everything in the list of references, both the items referenced before `\printbibliography` and also those after. How can I prevent this from happening and force biblatex to print only the items referenced in the project description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `refsegment`s to separate parts of your document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]
\newrefsegment

And later on: \fullcite{worman}
\end{document}
```

this leaves a potential for a shared bibliography and keeps disambiguation features.
Alternatively, you can use the `refsegment` environment instead of the `\newrefsegment` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsegment}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]
\end{refsegment}

And later on: \fullcite{worman}
\end{document}
```

If you prefer an approach where both parts of the document are completely separate, use `refsection`s

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer}
\printbibliography
\newrefsection

And later on: \fullcite{worman}
\end{document}
```

Here again, a `refsection` environment is also available.

Comment: Fantastic - just what I needed.